# transformations VS. change

Tags: vocabulary

> a change in behavioral and social patterns
>
> a transformation in behavioral and social patterns

Would anyone possibly show me whether or not there is any difference between those? Or even the latter could be considered a correct usage of transformation as to terms of psychology?

Any comment or feed-back would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question should be answered by simply checking a dictionary. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Change" could imply even a small or even meaningless difference. Degree is not implied. On the other hand, "transformation" implies a fundamental, wholesale change in something - "to transform" from one state to another. While I have no knowledge of the semantics of the word in the psychological profession, I do not believe the two statements are equivalent.